# cassandra slowed down when adding additional keyspaces

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, phpcassa, cassandra-cli

We have a cassandra development environment with 3 nodes cluster and each node with i3 processor and 8G memory. As we have keep increasing the number of keyspaces (i.e the nature of our application), at one point the performance of cassandra got slowed down (it was working fine with < 30 keyspaces).

What is the exact problem behind this?

---

Cassandra version - 2.0.6,
phpcassa

---

Comment: How many keyspaces and how many tables in each one?

Comment: Clusters performance was getting slow when it crossed over 25 KS and each KS contains 50+ CFs

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra allocates resources (e.g. memtables) for each column family. Having 1250 CFs is well above the rule-of-thumb limit of 100. You need to design your data model to have fewer column families.